# Azure Site Recovery - REST API, Powershell and Automation

Tags: rest, powershell, azure

Has anyone come up with a complete solution to protect and replicate VMs from on-prem (either VMware or HyperV) to Azure using either the REST API or the Powershell module?

I recently completed a POC with ASR and was able to replicate a couple dozen VMs associated with three different applications.  I replicated out of VMware and into Azure.  I was able to failover and failback successfully.

I did all of the POC work using the GUI (portal.azure.com).  Now I have to figure out how to protect ~2000 VMs and there is no way that I am going to do that with the GUI.  But the MS documentation has me running in circles.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/)

It would be very helpful if any of you can share the sequence of steps to protect and replicate a VM.  The MS documentation does not lay out how the various components (fabrics, protection policies, protection containers, protection items, etc.) are related to each other.

I do not need specific syntax.  The documentation does a passable job of detailing the syntax.  I could use some guidance on the task sequence.

If it helps to understand the bigger picture, my intention is to use a System Center Orchestrator runbook to ingest a CSV list of VMs, parse that out into input for the Azure REST API / Powershell, and then enable protection.

Thanks in advance for any assistance or guidance that you are able to provide.

Comment: well, just try to protect one vm with powershell (use the `-debug` switch) and see what rest calls it does, and just mimic that, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: That is what I am trying to sort out how to do.  Have you been able to protect a VM with powershell?  Which cmdlets did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can find recovery service API documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/recoveryservices/

When you have one definition put in place(manually from portal), you may also be able to study it from resource.azure.com to see how properties are composited. *not all resource available thru this portal

After that, you should be able to create template for either REST call or Resource Manager, depending on preference.

Comment: This link is helpful, given that ASR is closely related to Backup / Recovery Services.  Still not quite clear on the sequence.  Create Vault > Create Fabric > Create Container > Create Protected Item?   That all seems Azure centric.  Not clear on how to protect on-prem resources (VMware and HyperV).  Maybe need to query master or process server?

Comment: @dave562 I'm pretty sure you don't need to do all of that. (why would you need to create Fabric? or Containers?) Also, by logic `Create Protected Item` would work with `on-prem` servers also, would just require different query parameters (probably)

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Your question is what I am trying to understand. The fabric, containers, etc. are required values for other cmdlets, like creating a protected item.  If I do not create them, what does?  For example, get-..protectable item requires a -ProtectionContainer parameter.  You can Get..ProtectionContainer, which requires a -Fabric parameter.  There is not a "Create-..ProtectionContainer" command.

Comment: you don't need to create those on the fly, as you can create them once (if they are not provisioned with ASR, but they most likely are) @dave562

Comment: @dave562 you can learn your resource hierarchy from resource.azure.com once you have one provisioned manually. As 4c74356b41 suggested, you will likely only need to repeatedly create child resource that representing your recovery item.

Comment: @KaiZhao - Have you done this? I appreciate that you are trying to help, but I get the sense that you are talking about this theoretically and not from experience having done it.  There are not any ProtectionItems exposed through resourceS.azure.com.  Do you know how to associate a ProtectionItem (VM in this case) with a ProtectionContainer?

Comment: @4c74356b41  Have you done this? You say things like 'if they are not provisioned... but they most likely are' .  This leads me to believe that you are talking about this hypothetically.  I appreciate the effort at help, but a concrete example would help.  FWIW - This is being escalated internally at MS to the ASR product team.  Not even the MS engineer assigned to help knows exactly how this works.  It's almost as if they never expected anyone to actually use it, and just do everything through the GUI.

Comment: funny how you refer to MS engineer(s) as some kind of mythical all power creatures, whereas in fact they are mostly really-really bad. I haven't done exactly this, but I've done automation around Azure Backup and those things are provisioned when you create it and\or when you create a link to on prem stuff (this part you are not going to automate anyway) @dave562